# Java Web service using ssh (remote linux connection)

Tags: java, linux, service, ssh

I am more than novice in Linux. Nevertheless, I need to create a Java Web Service hosting in apache server in a Linux system. The Web service must use ssh to connect to a remote machine, create a txt file, execute a prog.exe (compiled C program in MPI) and then retrieve and return a single output value. The only thing that I do not know is how to connect remotely with the Web Service. In a shell will use something like:

```
ssh username@remotemachine
```

and then we will get a prompt for password.
Is it possible to send the password along with the ssh command? I have read that it is possible to connect in one shot with public/private keys but this project is my Master Thesis one and as a result, the machines are these of the uni. So, I do not want to mess with the technicians because most of the times simple do not help at all.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Ssh clients will recognize the following

`ssh username@remotemachine -pw'YourPassword'`

However, I used GanymedeSSH for Java and it had a method like this:

```
conn = new Connection(servername, 22);
conn.connect();
conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
session = conn.openSession();
```

And as long as you keep reference to your session, you will be able to use it to execute commands on the remote machine.

Comment: thanks very much! but I take an error: Bad port 'wpassword'. W is from the -pw

Comment: So, I will look the second option. Thanks a lot

Comment: With GanymedeSSH is actually quite easy to connect thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library [Jaramiko](http://www.lag.net/jaramiko/) to get over the problem (instead of calling ssh externally).